# Проверить пароль на надежность

Tags: python

Нужно написать функцию которая проверяет пароль:
Критерии надежного пароля:

Длина строки пароля восемь символов.
Содержит хотя бы одну букву в верхнем регистре.
Содержит хотя бы одну букву в нижнем регистре.
Содержит хотя бы одну цифру.
Функция is_valid_password должна вернуть True, если переданный в качестве параметра пароль отвечает требованиям надежности. В противном случае вернуть False.
мой код:

```py
def is_valid_password(password):
    
    
    b = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    c = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    d = "1234567890"
    
    if len(password) >= 8:
        for i in b:
            for y in c:
                for t in d:
                    if i and y and t in password:
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
    else:
        return False
```

но когда `` is_valid_password('`ozal.2N') == False ``, а должно быть `True`,почему считает кавычки?

Comment: если элементы вот этих трех списков входят в пароль ,вот так я это понимаю

Comment: ну я ответил что значит фраза i and y and t in password

Comment: да чего ты так душишь?)

Comment: Я прошу вас критически отнестись к коду который вы пишите. Если вы сами поймёте что именно с ним не так, у вас сформируется важный навык. Если я напишу как исправить, вы просто исправите. Не беспокойтесь, я сейчас дам полный ответ и сотру свои комментарии. Уже стёр.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разберём выражение `i and y and t in password`. Из [таблицы приоритетов операторов](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) следует что `in` имеет приоритет выше чем `and` и скобки надо расставить так: `(i and y) and (t in password)`. В первой итерации цикла выражение вычисляется как `('A' and 'a') and ('1' in password)`. Оператор `and` значения `'A'` и `'a'` воспринимает как истину. Получаем значение `'1' in password`. Но единицы в пароле нет, поэтому выражение ложно.

Сколько раз выполняется тело цикла? Если условие истинно, цикл немедленно прерывается. Если условие ложно, тоже. То есть, ваш код равносилен следующему:

```
def is_valid_password(password):
    if len(password) >= 8:
        if 'A' and 'a' and '1' in password:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Это нужно поправить. Если буквально следовать описанию то получится вот это:

```
def has_uppercase(password):
    for c in password:
        if c in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ':
            return True
    return False

def has_lowercase(password):
    for c in password:
        if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            return True
    return False

def has_digit(password):
    for c in password:
        if c in '1234567890':
            return True
    return False

def is_valid_password(password):
    
    # Длина строки пароля восемь символов.
    if len(password) != 8:
        return False

    # Содержит хотя бы одну букву в верхнем регистре.
    if not has_uppercase(password):
        return False

    # Содержит хотя бы одну букву в нижнем регистре.
    if not has_lowercase(password):
        return False

    # Содержит хотя бы одну цифру.
    if not has_digit(password):
        return False

    # Функция is_valid_password должна вернуть True,
    # если переданный в качестве параметра пароль отвечает требованиям надежности.
    return True
```

Функции `has_...` так похожи что их можно свести в одну:

```
def has_char(password, char_set):
    for c in password:
        if c in char_set:
            return True
    return False


def is_valid_password(password):
    
    # Длина строки пароля восемь символов.
    if len(password) != 8:
        return False

    # Содержит хотя бы одну букву в верхнем регистре.
    if not has_char(password, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
        return False

    # Содержит хотя бы одну букву в нижнем регистре.
    if not has_char(password, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
        return False

    # Содержит хотя бы одну цифру.
    if not has_char(password, '1234567890'):
        return False

    # Функция is_valid_password должна вернуть True,
    # если переданный в качестве параметра пароль отвечает требованиям надежности.
    return True
```

Если вы заботитесь о производительности то желательно использовать множества:

```
upper_set = set('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
lower_set = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
digit_set = set('1234567890')


def is_valid_password(password):
    
    # Длина строки пароля восемь символов.
    if len(password) != 8:
        return False

    password_set = set(password)

    # Содержит хотя бы одну букву в верхнем регистре.
    if not password_set & upper_set:
        return False

    # Содержит хотя бы одну букву в нижнем регистре.
    if not password_set & lower_set:
        return False

    # Содержит хотя бы одну цифру.
    if not password_set & digit_set:
        return False

    # Функция is_valid_password должна вернуть True,
    # если переданный в качестве параметра пароль отвечает требованиям надежности.
    return True
```

И наконец финальный код:

```
upper_set = set('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
lower_set = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
digit_set = set('1234567890')


def is_valid_password(password):
    
    # Длина строки пароля восемь символов.
    if len(password) != 8:
        return False

    password_set = set(password)

    # Содержит хотя бы одну букву в верхнем регистре.
    # Содержит хотя бы одну букву в нижнем регистре.
    # Содержит хотя бы одну цифру.
    # Функция is_valid_password должна вернуть True,
    # если переданный в качестве параметра пароль отвечает требованиям надежности.
    return \
        password_set & upper_set and \
        password_set & lower_set and \
        password_set & digit_set
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое за подробный разбор

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, к вашему великолепному разбору добавил для Гая по отладке ещё немного в другом вопросе: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423731/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc/1423738#1423738>

Comment: @Сергей, отличный ответ. Жаль что повод для наших ответов не такой уж значительный. Зато отличная тренировка навыков изложения. :)

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, маленькие камушки страгивают большие лавины. В начале пути приводить примеры лучше на совсем простых случаях. Методология всё равно одинакова, что для сложнейших программ, что для простых. Было бы желание у вопрошающего научиться ей и научиться в результате задавать более сложные вопросы себе и миру:-).

Answer (score 4):

я бы подправил логику и спрашивал бы содержится ли символ в определенном наборе, a результаты попаданий хранил бы в списке. После того как все символы строки пароля были проверены спросить все ли попадания существуют с помощью метода `all()`

```py
import string


def is_valid_password(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return False
    mass = [False, False, False]
    for letter in password:
        if letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            mass[0] = True
        if letter in string.ascii_uppercase:
            mass[1] = True
        if letter in string.digits:
            mass[2] = True
    if all(mass):
        return True
    return False
```

Чтобы не перечислять символы и не писать вручную наборы, они уже существуют в `string`.

Comment: а если без string?

Comment: @Гай ну укажите ваши переменные, разницы в этом большой не будет. Только в чем сомнение использования? Это встроенно

Comment: Спасибо ,оказывается все так просто

Comment: @Гай на здоровье. не забывайте оценивать ответы и помечать принятые.

Answer (score 1):

эту проверку можно сделать еще так:

```
def is_valid_password(password):
   
    b = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    c = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    d = "1234567890"
    up = lw = dg = False
    
    if len(password) >= 8:
        for i in password:
            if i in b: up = True
            if i in c: lw = True
            if i in d: dg = True
    
    return up and lw and dg

is_valid_password('Password1')  # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Для любителей однострочных (не совсем) решений.

```
def valid_password(password: str):
    return all((any(map(str.islower, password)),
               any(map(str.isupper, password)),
               any(map(str.isnumeric, password)),
               len(password) == 8))


print(valid_password('`ozal.2N'))
```

Вывод

```
True
```

Comment: Лямбды не нужны: `map(lambda x: x.islower(), password)` -> `map(str.islower, password)` и так по всем строковым функциям.

Comment: Да, вы правы, исправил.