# Ошибка в коде генерации пароля. Просьба помочь найти причину, дать пояснение

Tags: python

**Проблема:** код ниже выдает невалидный пароль. Просьба подсказать причину, пояснить, как сделать правильно. Буду рад любой помощи.
Приведенный код близок к минимально необходимому к воспроизведению проблемы.

**Исходная задача:** написать функцию get_password, которая сгенерирует нам случайный надежный пароль и вернет его. Алгоритм простой — мы генерируем пароль с помощью функции get_random_password и, если он проходит надежность проверкой функцией is_valid_password, возвращаем его, если нет — повторяем итерацию снова.

```
    from random import randint
      
    
    def get_random_password():
        result = ""
        count = 0
        while count < 8:
            random_symbol = chr(randint(40, 126))
            result = result + random_symbol
            count = count + 1
        return result


    def is_valid_password(password):
        has_upper = False
        has_lower = False
        has_num = False
        for ch in password:
            if "A" <= ch <= "Z":
                has_upper = True
            elif "a" <= ch <= "z":
                has_lower = True
            elif "0" <= ch <= "9":
                has_num = True
        if len(password) == 8 and has_upper and has_lower and has_num:
            return True
        return False


    def get_password():    
        count = 0
        while count < 10:
            if is_valid_password(get_random_password()) == True:
                return (get_random_password())                
            else:
                pass
            count += 1
```

Comment: В строке `return (get_random_password())` вы генерируете абсолютно новый пароль, который никогда не проходил проверку функцией `is_valid_password`

Comment: а какой тогда будет который проходил проверку?

Comment: Проверку проходил пароль, который генерируется строчкой выше

Comment: не пойму как это записать

Comment: @Гай, я вижу, вы человек, активно генерирующий вопросы. Вы сами коды пишете? Если да, и вам это интересно, умеете ли вы отлаживать пошагово в отдадчике? (или хоть с отладочной печатью). Может вам с этим помочь? (это легко и интересно, сли программировать нравится)

Comment: Относительно "не пойму как это записать" - задумайтесь, зачем нам нужны переменные?

Comment: Да,сам пишу.Как видите,не очень-то и получается.Был бы рад любой помощи)

Comment: Это нормально, что сначала не получается. Вот ссылка, как идеально отлаживать программу <https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/>, но это сложновато, хотя советую прочесть и понять основное. В более простом варианте - в каждом случае, когда работает не так, как хочется, прокрутите в голове - что вы ожидаете на выхода каждого шага в подозрительной части. Дальше выводите входные и выходные параметры этой части функцией `print` или в отладчике (например, PyCharm). См. пример с `print` в ответе ниже для данного случая.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо,все просмотрю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ниже - ваша функция с ошибкой, переделанная под отладочную печать. Все сложные строки разбиты на части, результаты распечатываются. Вы сможете увидеть из печати, что temp_pass_1 оказывается не равен temp_pass_2, и из этого понятно, в чём дело.
Теперь можно убрать все временные переменные и переделать программу, как показано во второй части.

Можно и не использовать отладочную печать, а (лучше!) поставить PyCharm и запускать программу Shift+F9, поставив слева красную точку щелчком мыши на каждой подозрительной строке. Далее, нажимая F8, вы сможете идти по шагам и видеть значения переменных прямо в тексте кода (поищите видео по PyChаrm, если короткое пояснение не очень понятно).

Еще оптимальнее просто в голове прокручивать, как всё должно быть, глядя на код, но это умение придёт со временем.

```
def get_password():
    count = 0
    while count < 10:
        temp_pass_1 = get_random_password()
        print (temp_pass_1)
        if is_valid_password(temp_pass_1) == True:
            temp_pass_2 = get_random_password()
            print(temp_pass_2)
            return (temp_pass_2)
        else:
            pass
        count += 1

relaible_password = get_password()
print (relaible_password)
```

Исправленный код в результате такой отладки:

```
def get_password():
    count = 0
    while count < 10:
        # Убрали ошибку: ввели переменную, чтобы не изменялось значение
        random_password = get_random_password()
        # Улучшили: равенство True проверяется по умолчанию,так что убрали конец строки
        if is_valid_password(random_password):
            return (random_password)
        else:
            pass
        count += 1
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,еще раз выручаете