# Ошибка TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python

Задание: Написать программу, которая сформирует новый список, в котором изменены местами две строки: строка, содержащая максимальный элемент, и строка, содержащая минимальный элемент.

```
from random import randint

x = int(7)
y = int(11)
matrix = [[randint(0, 20) for a in range(y)] for b in range(x)]
print("first matrix: ")
for i in range(x):
    print(matrix[i])

newmatrix = []
mini = int(matrix[0][0])
maxi = int(matrix[0][0])
a = 0
b = 0
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if matrix[i][j] > maxi:
            maxi = matrix[i]
            a = i
        if matrix[i][j] < mini:
            mini = matrix[i]
            b = i


for i in range(len(matrix)):
    newmatrix[i] = matrix[a][i]
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix[a][i] = matrix[b][i]
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    matrix[b][i] = newmatrix[i]
print("second matrix: ")
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    print(matrix[i])
```

Ошибка:

```
line 19, in <module>
    if matrix[i][j] < mini:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Пожалуйста объясните в чём ошибка и как её исправить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же сами `mini = matrix[i]` сделали, превратив `mini` в список. Как его далее сравнивать с элементом списка типа `int`?

Предлагаемая коррекция ниже:

```
        if matrix[i][j] > maxi:
            maxi = matrix[i][j]
            a = i
        if matrix[i][j] < mini:
            mini = matrix[i][j]
            b = i
```

Следующую ошибку рекомендую исправить самому с помощью отладчика. Я сам использую PyCharm.
Вот здесь очень простая и короткая рекомендация по отладке в моём ответе на другой вопрос:
[Ошибка в коде генерации пароля. Просьба помочь найти причину, дать пояснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423731/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%b1%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1423738#1423738)