# Ошибка системы уровней

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py

этот код должен проверять, достиг ли xp участника количества, необходимого для его повышения (2500 + 100 * на уровень участника)
В конце концов он выводит эту ошибку :

```
2328 2 774143521568718849 0 - принт
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\путь\bot-main\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\путь\bot-main\cogs\other.py", line 354, in on_message
    uxp = self.collection.find_one({'_id': user.id})['xp']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Вот код:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if self.bot.user == message.author:
            return
        user = message.author
        data = self.collection.find_one({'_id': user.id})
        msg_len = len(message.content)
        rn = random.randint(1, 3)
        exp1 = msg_len * rn
        exp = round(exp1)
        uxp = self.collection.find_one({'_id': user.id})['xp']
        ulvl = self.collection.find_one({'_id': user.id})['lvl']
        ubal = self.collection.find_one({'_id': user.id})['balance'] #для теста брала
        print(uxp, ulvl, user.id, ubal)
        if uxp >= 2500 + 100 * ulvl:
            self.collection.update_one({'_id': user.id}, {'$set': {'lvl': data['lvl'] + 1}})
            self.collection.update_one({'_id': user.id}, {'$set': {'xp': 0}})
            emb = discord.Embed(title=f"**{user.name} поднял уровень!**", description=f'Теперь у него {data["xp"]}',
                                colour=discord.Color.random())
            emb.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
            await message.channel.send(emb=emb, delete_after=20)
            await message.add_reaction("✅")
            await asyncio.sleep(20)
            await message.delete()

        else:
            self.collection.update_one({'_id': user.id}, {'$set': {'xp': data['xp'] + exp}})
```

Comment: А чего вы хотели добиться такой проверкой - как именно она должна работать (порядок действий можете расписать)?

Comment: if self.collection.find_one({"_id": user.id})["xp"] - находит пользователя в db и его xp

>= 2500 + 100 * self.collection.find_one({"_id": user.id})["lvl"]: - если оно больше чем 2500+100* на (находит юзера в db и его лвл, умножает 100 на лвл) то он обновляет уровень (lvl+1) и обнуляет xp
Если же xp не превысил необходимый то он просто добавляет 50xp за сообщение

Comment: @Сергей вот, расписала

Comment: `subscriptable` - это квадратные скобки, поэтому в `self.collection.find_one({"_id": user.id})["xp"]` у вас `self.collection.find_one({"_id": user.id})` вернул `None`. Лучше вместо повторения `self.collection.find_one({"_id": user.id})` вынесите значение в отдельную переменную и заодно проверьте ее значение - чтобы ругаться если не будет найден пользователь

Comment: if data['xp'] >= 2500 + 100 * \
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
 @gil9red

Comment: Если ругается даже на короткую `if data['xp'] >= 2500 + 100 * `, то значит, что `data` - `NoneType`. Либо её система не распознаёт, либо пользователя не видит. В общем, разбирайте на мелкие части всю эту конструкцию, находите самую мелкую часть, на которую ругаются, проверяйте её тип (`type (data)`, например) и понимайте, почему он такой, а не другой.

Comment: @EternityHalcyon, нужно проверять что приходит из `find_one`, у вас там `None`, а значит в `data` будет `None`: вам нужно добавить проверку на `None` (типа `if not data` или `if data is None`, а там ругаться, например `raise Exception(f'Не удалось найти данные по _id={user.id}')`). И нужно выяснить почему `None` приходит. Мб нет данных или запрос неправильный

Comment: Вот короткие советы по отладке в ответе на другой вопрос, если нужно: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423731/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/1423738#1423738>

Comment: добавила print к этим данным, они выводятся. @gil9red

Comment: Что-то у вас не так:-) Советую добавить в вопрос разбитый на кусочки код с вашими ` print `. Написать, что именно выводится. В идеале, в виде минимально воспроизводимого примера, чтобы участники сообщества могли проверить.

Comment: Обновляю пост, смотрите выше.

Comment: при попытке запуска получаю: `name 'commands' is not defined`, т.е. пример не воспроизводимый:-(

Comment: если ругается на `uxp = self.collection.find_one({'_id': user.id})['xp']` - то выведите на печать до этой строки  отдельно: 1) часть словаря с {'_id': user.id}; 2) ключ '_id'; 3) значение по этому ключу; 4) результат `self.collection.find_one({'_id': user.id})`; 5) результат self.collection.find_one({'_id': user.id})['xp']. И типы в каждом случае. Сравните с тем, что ожидаете увидеть.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, код не совсем полон. Но по тому что есть, функция по нахождению записи self.collection.find_one() не нашла совпадений. Проверьте правильно ли вы вписали в эту функции данные. Возможно опечатка?
Или попросту пользователь еще не был добавлен в бд, а уже идет проверка его xp

Comment: Пользователи добавлены все 540) опечаток нет

Comment: Тогда функция self.collection.find_one({"_id": user.id}) должна была вернуть вам значение об этом пользователе из бд, но ответ None, здесь и ошибка, тк у объекта None нельзя выбирать элементы)

Поэтому или юзер не был найден в бд, или входящие данные в функцию не корректны, без фул кода мало что скажешь..
Можно только делать проверку на ответ из этой функции, если None, пользователь не найден в бд, значит его нужно зарегистрировать, а после регистрации дать те xp и дальше раскручивать дело)

Comment: все пользователи автоматом в БЗ заносятся как только заходят на серв + эта ошибка работает даже на меня, что странно