# bs4 Ошибка str не могу понять почему

Tags: python, aiogram, beautiful-soup

Вылазит ошибка

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\sa1nt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError('can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sa1nt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\sa1nt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\sa1nt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\sa1nt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\sa1nt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\sa1nt\Desktop\parser.py", line 41, in parser
    caption="<b>" + name + "<b>\n<i>" + price + f"<i>\n<a href='{url}'> Ссылка на сайт</a>",
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Код вот такой

```
from urllib import request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher,executor,types


bot = Bot("")
dp = Dispatcher(bot) 

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.message):
   await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """
Привет, я бот который парсит сообщения в <b><a href="https://lalafo.kg"> lalafo</a></b>

Для того, что чтобы я отправил тебе объявления, введи в поле его названия...""",
parse_mode = 'html', disable_web_page_preview=1)
   
   
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def parser(message: types.message):
   url="https://lalafo.kg/kyrgyzstan/q-" + message.text
   request = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
   
   all_link = soup.find_all("a", class_="adTile-title")
   for link in all_link:
      url = "https://lalafo.kg/" + link["href"]
      request = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
      
      name = soup.find("h1", class_="Heading secondary-small")
       
      price = soup.find("a", class_="heading")
      
      tel = soup.find("a", class_='linkButton medium secondary')
      
      img = soup.find("div", class_="carousel__img-wrap")

      
      await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img,
      caption="<b>" + name + "<b>\n<i>" + price + f"<i>\n<a href='{url}'> Ссылка на сайт</a>",
      parse_mode='html')
      
      
executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Как исправить?
И когда добавляешь такой код

```
img = soup.find("div", class_="carousel__img-wrap")
img = img.findChildren("img")[0]
img = "https://lalafo.kg/" + img["src"]
```

Жалуется на ошибку атрибута findChildren

Comment: 1) Зачем программировать, вообще не понимая, как устранять ошибки? (Просьба ответить, интересно же). Научиться этому - пара часов. 2) Очевидно же, что у вас не получен один из компонентов (`name`, `price` и т.д.) - потому и `NoneType`. Ставьте отладочную печать или по шагам идите (см.ниже ссылку  на совет короткий, как это делать) 3) Не совмещайте два вопроса в одной теме. Открывайте другой, как отладитесь, но ошибку - полностью приводить надо, как тут сделано.

Comment: вот ссылка: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423731/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/1423738#1423738>

Comment: А почему бы и нет?) Все когда-то начинали.

Comment: Я, разумеется, начинал не так. Успеха с таким подходом...