# Что делаю не так ? Нужно удалить в списке словарей пустые значение и null

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

есть код который должен удалить пустые значение, но на выходе он выдает:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Как можно это обойти или как сделать правильно ?

Сам код:

```
awe = ['null', '']
result = []
for res in list_1:
    if res['Client'] not in awe:
        result.append(res)
print(result)
```

входные данные:

```
    [
       {
          "Client": [],
          "description": ""
       },
       {
          "Client": [],
          "description": ""
       },
       null,
       {
          "Client": [],
          "description": ""
       },
       {
          "Client": [
             "Dima"
          ],
          "description": "UX"
       },
       null,
       {
          "Client": [
             "Andrey"
          ],
          "description": It "
       }]
```

Пытался удалить вначале в списке null а потом в словаре пустые значение, все равно ошибка

Comment: res['Client'] у вас - список. а сравниваете вы его со строками. поэтому вам нужно будет проходить еще по всем элементам res['Client'] и их уже сравнивать с awe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Однострочник для разнообразия, в дополнение к ответу Сергея:

```py
result = [res for res in filter(None, list_1) if res['Client']]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Оставаясь в вашей логике, надо:

1. Заменить Null (не понимаю, как Python пропустил у вас в входных данных?) на `None` в входных данных;
2. Сначала проверять на `None` (ошибку у вас выдает на этом сравнении, что логично. И ставим в одну строку в коде ниже, пользуясь правилом, что если первая проверка не проходит, то вторую не выполнит Python), а затем уже на пустой список в словаре, раз у вас там пустой список (а не на '').

Вот так работает - выдает
[{'Client': ['Dima'], 'description': 'UX'}, {'Client': ['Andrey'], 'description': 'It'}]:

```
list_1=[
   {
      "Client": [],
      "description": ""
   },
   {
      "Client": [],
      "description": ""
   },
   None,
   {
      "Client": [],
      "description": ""
   },
   {
      "Client": [
         "Dima"
      ],
      "description": "UX"
   },
    None,
   {
      "Client": [
         "Andrey"
      ],
      "description": "It"
   }]

result = []
for res in list_1:   
    if res and res['Client'] !=[]:
            result.append(res)
print(result)
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: Спасибо, начинаю потихоньку понимать, а то все время путаюсь где что у меня и как/ Надо структуру данных понимать :(

Comment: В отладчик еще можно было засунуть - всё бы увидели. Или отладочную печать. Почитайте мой ответ на этот вопрос - тут  советы по отладке: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423731/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/1423738#1423738>

Comment: `res['Client'] !=[]` можно тоже оставить только `res['Client']`, не пустой будет `True`

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, да, я оставил с [] для избежания недоразумений и для наглядности.